# Parsing through a text file

Tags: python

I have a list of 200 names in a text file. all of the characters in the names are lowercase and vary from 6 characters or 7 characters and are divided into several headings. Some have subheadings. I try to split based on space but it ends up splitting the text file up by the space between each section of names. Some `\n` is also printed. I have 2 different ideas and am stuck on both.

```
Header
subheading
namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamename


Heading


Header
subheading
namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamename
```

In the end I am trying to ignore the header and subheader (which vary between all caps, all lowercaps, and a mix of both) and just print the names. I started by trying to append everything as a list, but, because I couldn't properly parse through the text, I ended up getting errors or it prints each letter of each string individually.

```
path_to_file = 'pathgoeshere'

check_list = []

for word in open(path_to_file).read()
    username = str(word)
    check_list.append(username)
    print username

List = open(path_to_file).readlines()
print List


for x in List:
    user_name = str(x)
    if user_name.lower():
      print user_name
```

In my actual code it is formatted properly, but this is the jist of what I was looking for.

In the end I am looking to parse through and count the names without counting the extraneous text that I do not need.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand exactly what you're after. But this should get you started (ignore the heading and subheading and just print all the names):

```
with open('pathgoeshere') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if any(char.isupper() for char in line): continue
        print line
```

Since your names (the stuff you care about) is in all lowercase, you should be able to get away with simply testing if a line has uppercase characters

Comment: Sorry if my question sounded confusing. Basically I have a lot of text (headers, subheaders, usernames). The characters are a mixture of all capitalized, all lowercase, or a mix of both. The usernames are all lower case and are either 6 or 7 characters long. I am trying to parse out the usernames from the rest of the text without getting any of the subheader or header information mixed in.

Comment: @Smithw1: have you tried running my code? It should do what you're asking

Comment: Thank you for the help. Initially when I ran the code, it returned some null values, but after some tweaking we managed to get it to work. Your code was a great starting point. It did contain extraneous values I had to take care so the any(char.isupper()) had to be modified. 

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: types = [2 , 3, 4, 5, 6]

     include = "INCLUDE"
    with open(path_to_file) as infile:
       for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if include not in line:
           if "GROUP" in line:
            line2 = str(line).split(" ")
            check_list.append(line2)

total_users = 0
for type in types:
    print check_list[type][1] + " " + str(len(check_list[type][2:]))
    total_users = total_users + len(check_list[type][2:])

print "Total Licenses Users: " + str(total_users)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thinking:

- Names only seem to come after `Header` and `subheading`
- `split` by `\n` and find the last line in each group of lines greater than 3.

---

```
txt = """Header
subheading
namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamename


Heading


Header
subheading
namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamename
"""

# split text
s = pd.Series(txt.split('\n'))

# regex to find lines with nothing but whitespace
blanks = s.str.match(r'^\s*$')

# assign groups of lines starting with the first non blank
# filter groups with `~blanks` to focus on just non blank lines
non_blank_groups = (~blanks & blanks.shift().fillna(True)).cumsum().loc[~blanks]

# get value counts of the groups to get rid of groups of lines
# with only one line like `Heading`
value_counts = non_blank_groups.value_counts()

# filter `non_blank_groups` with only the groups with more than 2 lines
groups = non_blank_groups[non_blank_groups.isin(value_counts.index[value_counts.ge(3)])]

# finally, groupby and grab last one
s.groupby(groups).last()

1.0    namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamena...
3.0    namenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamenamena...
dtype: object
```